# How to convert times over 24:00:00 in R

Tags: r

In R I have this data.frame

```
24:43:30 23:16:02 14:05:44 11:44:30 ...
```

Note that some of the times are **over** 24:00:00 ! In fact all my times are within `02:00:00` to `25:59:59`.

I want to subtract all entries in my dataset `data` with 2 hours. This way I get a regular data-set. How can I do this?

I tried this

```
strptime(data, format="%H:%M:%S") - 2*60*60
```

and this work for all entries below `23:59:59`. For all entries above I simply get `NA` since the `strptime` command produce `NA` to all entries above `23:59:59`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `lubridate` package can make the job easier!

```
> library(lubridate)
> t <- '24:43:30'
> hms(t) - hms('2:0:0')
[1] "22H 43M 30S"
```

Update:

Converting the date back to text!

```
> substr(strptime(hms(t) - hms('2:0:0'),format='%HH %MM %SS'),12,20)
[1] "22:43:30"
```

Adding [@RHertel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4770166/rhertel)'s update:

```
format(strptime(hms(t) - hms('2:0:0'),format='%HH %MM %SS'),format='%H:%M:%S')
```

Better way of formating the lubridate object:

```
s <- hms('02:23:58) - hms('2:0:0')
paste(hour(s),minute(s),second(s),sep=":")
"0:23:58"
```

Comment: I can get this to run and it works! How can I convert this output back to the original format like "18:14:20" ?

Comment: For some reason it produce NA for times like "02:23:58". Why is that?

Comment: @user6678274 updated the answer, please check the last one!

Comment: @RHertel Yes in that case hour(s) will return 0

Comment: An alternative way is to divide the dataset, say "02:00:00" to "23:59:59" and solve it normal. Then take the part "24:00:00" to "25:59:59" and solve it the 'lubridate' way in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although the answer by [@amrrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5086335/amrrs) solves the main problem, the formatting could remain an issue because `hms()` does not provide a uniform output. This is best shown with an example:

```
library(lubridate)
hms("01:23:45")
#[1] "1H 23M 45S"
hms("00:23:45")
#[1] "23M 45S"
hms("00:00:45")
#[1] "45S"
```

Depending on the time passed to `hms()` the output may or may not contain an entry for the hours and for the minutes. Moreover leading zeros are omitted in single-digit values of hours, minutes and seconds. This can result pretty much in a formatting nightmare if one tries to put that data into a common form.

To resolve this difficulty one could first convert the time into a duration with lubridate's `as.duration()` function. Then, the duration in seconds can be transformed into a POSIXct object from which the hours, minutes, and seconds can be extracted easily with `format()`:

```
times <- c("24:43:30", "23:16:02", "14:05:44", "11:44:30", "02:00:12")
shifted_times <- hms(times) - hms("02:00:00")
format(.POSIXct(as.duration(shifted_times),tz="GMT"), "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "22:43:30" "21:16:02" "12:05:44" "09:44:30" "00:00:12"
```

The last entry "02:00:12" would have caused difficulties if `shifted_times` had been passed to `strptime()`.